# Store Oauth token using java without cookies

Tags: java, oauth, access-token

I am fairly new to REST.I am developing a java library(No frameworks used) to handle all REST API calls.I want this API to handle storing the oauth credentials that I get on first hit, so that I do not need to request it for subsequent calls till the token expires. 
I have read a lot about storing in cookies but that approach did not work for me. I do not have a response or request object. I do not want to store the token in DB as of now, What could be the next best way to store oauth token until it expires.

Can someone suggest an approach that does not involve cookies or DB.

Comment: What do you want to store exactly on your server? The access token? How would you verify that the request is authenticated if you do not request that very token?

Comment: @petul, I want to store the access token. I intent to request it once, store it and use until it expires and re-request once its no longer valid. Token is valid for 1 hour in my case.

Comment: So you are basically going to map an IP with the token? I'm just wondering how you are going to determine that two separate HTTP requests are on behalf of the same subject, when you don't have a token in the header at all.

Comment: More like a machine with the token, if I save the token in users local storage then I can validate any request going through that system with that token as valid request. Does this approach sound not okay?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question text I think. You will still send the token on every request in the header, I somehow thought you want to avoid sending anything from the client. In that case, if you do not want to save it in a db (which would make most sense), you can use any form of in-memory collection (HashTable) storing a Token class with token, expire-time etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html

This might be helpful for you.